# how to follow or unfollow a user in instagram api(java,implicit way)

Tags: java, api, instagram

[image]

I'm trying to follow or unfollow user using instagram api in java
here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                       String urlString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+USERID+"/relationship?access_token="+TOKEN; // URL to call

      String data = (URLEncoder.encode("action:unfollow")); //data to post
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(data);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                out.close();
                urlConnection.connect();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

    }
```

i want unfollow a user by this code but this does not work
thanks in advance

edit:
**SOLVED!**

URLEncoder should be removed and should use `=` instead of `:`
        String data = ("action=unfollow"); //data to post
when i added inputString code worked nicely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pass 'action=unfollow' on your URLEncoder.encode()

Comment: I'm creating a app using javascript and i'm using a url like that: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&action=approve`

Comment: even when i used this in address bar user not unfollowed , but thanks for sharing that url i got something,for now result is:
{"data": {"outgoing_status": "follows", "incoming_status": "followed_by", "target_user_is_private": false}, "meta": {"code": 200}}
maybe thats for permission,i will check it

Comment: problem is not for permission,maybe its a bug,when i use apigee for testing that works(http://s8.picofile.com/file/8306970600/instagram_relation.png) but when i use in code or browser addressbar....  
anyway,thanks for helping

Comment: Have you added the user that you trying to unfollow as a test user on the client manager on instagram api site?

Comment: And yes, you need to ask for the permission `relationships` when getting the user token.

Comment: yeah i have  checked it,permission granted and i really dont understand whats the problem,as i said when i use that address in apigee(using post method for setting action=unfollow) that works

Answer (score 0):

Note that new "relationship" permissions are no longer available from Instagram. Do you already have this permission? I'd like to hear how you're using it
instagram.com/developer/authorization/

Comment: as I remember I granted relationship permission and something else, the problem was with my code

Comment: What was the app? I'd be interested in checking it out and may have a few questions about it @winner1

Comment: I was trying to make an app for monitoring followers, but I tried to test my 
java code in NetBeans IDE instead of android app(for getting the result faster)

Comment: Cool. Is the app still available or functioning? You can also email me at my name at gmail

Comment: unfortunately i didn't finished that project for some reason :(